# How to allow a genetic algorithm to build a generic mathematical formula?

Tags: algorithms, random-variables

Assume I have 4 known numbers, all in a 0-400 range, as follows:

```
Variable1   Variable2   Variable3   Variable4
0-400       0-400       0-400       0-400
```

I also know that there is a relation between the numbers.

I would like to use a genetic algorithm (computer code) to estimate/approximiate Variable2 and Variable3 based on Variables 1 and 4.

How can I write the following into a genetic algorithm:

```
Variable2=?
Variable3=?
```

Where `?` could be any mathematical function (+/-/*/:/√/^2/cos/sin/tan/etc.) involving Variables2 and 3

In other words; how can I define Variable2 and Variable3 as the outcome of a mathematical formula so that estimation by a computer algorithm becomes possible? The genetic algorithm will be able optimize the mattowards the already-known Variable2 and Variable3.

In other words, I want the genetic algorithm to build a mathematical formula. I am not sure how to approach this. The genetic algorithm software I use can use as many variables as is needed, and they can be in disparate ranges.

So for example, I could write my algorithm like this easily;

```
Variable2=Variable1(op)Variable4
Variable3=Variable1(op)Variable4
```

Where `Variable1` is the first variable for the genetic algorithm, with a range of `0-400`, and `Variable4` is the second variable for the genetic algorithm, with a range of `0-400`, and finally `(op)` is the third variable for the genetic algorithm, for example with a range of `1-4` where `1` stands for `+`, `2` for `-`, `3` for `*`, `4` for `:` etc.

However, the complexity of this algorithm is very limited and crude; it is not optimized towards a nice and complex real estimation algorithm. Also, as soon as a secondary operator is introduced, for example:

```
Variable2=Variable1(op)Variable4(op)[Variable1 or Variable4]
Variable3=Variable1(op)Variable4(op)[Variable1 or Variable4]
```

As you can see, the coding complexity for something like this would greatly increase, there may be a need to use `(` and `)` to prioritize mathematical calculations, and so on. And the more times the variables and various mathematical

Is there a much more straightforward

Comment: This might be a question more suited for [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetic-algorithms).

Comment: Looking for an answer